# Display PDF on iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

i m looking for a way to display PDFs on iOS - for sure i could use a webView but are there some other ways?
Maybe some frameworks (i did not find any), that offer some more features like "draw on pdf etc"

Comment: Go through this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-displaying-pdf-documents--mobile-11145

Answer (score 1):

It depend on what you want free or fee. I see a lot framework. Also It write with `Objective-C`. But it's not problem because you can use it with Bridging-Header.

I have used to [PDKFkit](https://pspdfkit.com/) but it have fee.

I see this compare, I think you can reference it [Compare framework pdf iOS](http://www.binpress.com/blog/2014/07/28/comparing-ios-pdf-libraries/)

Maybe It library can be fit what you want: [vfr/Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

Comment: Well it should be a free version at all:-).

Comment: @FabianBoulegue Try lib on my update. My friend have used it before go to PDFfkit.